# Typescript Redux Action Generic with Iterable Type

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux

**Solved:** If you run into this exact issue, don't make my bonehead mistake. I was trying to deconstruct an object in `Object.assign` when I should have just been passing the object. [@Eldar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12354911/eldar) and [@Akxe](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3001856/akxe) were kind enough to put fresh eyes on the code and help me see my mistake in the comments.

---

**Problem:** I'm trying to create a reusable Entity for my redux actions in typescript so I can just pass a type in the reducer, but it's complaining that my type is not iterable and I'm not sure how to solve this. I've blindly tried adding `typeof` and `Iterable` to no avail, so I'm looking for a little help and explanation.

I have an Entity for my user as:

```js
export default interface UserEntity {
  uid: string | null;
  firstName: string | null;
}
```

and created a generic Entity for my action as:

```js
export default interface StoreAction<T> {
  payload: T;
  type: string;
}
```

In my reducer, I hoped to implement it like this:

```js
const initialState: UserEntity = {
  uid: null,
  firstName: null,
};
export default (state = initialState, action: StoreAction<UserEntity>) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'Some string':
      return Object.assign({}, state, ...action.payload); // Warning that action.payload is not iterable
    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```

but VS Code is complaining `Type 'UserEntity' must have a '[Symbol.iterator]()' method that returns an iterator.` While I understand what it's complaining about, I'm at a loss on how to solve it.

If it's not obvious here, I want to pass my action a payload of json in the structure of this `UserEntity` and then be able to use the spread operator to merge it with my redux state. And I was hoping to make this a generic because some actions will have arrays, some might just be a boolean, etc. The redux site [gives similar examples showing spread operators with interfaces](https://redux.js.org/recipes/usage-with-typescript#type-checking-reducers) as if this should work, but I'm clearly missing something in mine.

**Edit**: Adding my tsconfig.json:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "esnext",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "lib": [
      "es6"
    ],
    "allowJs": true,
    "jsx": "react-native",
    "noEmit": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "strict": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "babel.config.js",
    "metro.config.js",
    "jest.config.js"
  ]
}
```

Comment: In those examples, Action types are re-exported with type aliases. Like: `export type SystemActionTypes = UpdateSessionAction`. And sharing your ts.config file would be useful.

Comment: I added my tsconfig. I'll try types - would you suggest I export my interface as a type (or switch it to a type), or that each action needs to be a type? I didn't see that they did this, so I'll tinker but in the spirit of reusability, I think I'd rather have an action factory and be able to pass it an action type string and a variable type payload. Suggestions? Thanks!

Comment: You should not deconstruct it there..., object deconstruction is only valid while inside object definition. The error is valid. Just remove those three dots or use `{ ...state, ...action.payload }`

Comment: @Akxe is right if you change it to : `return Object.assign({}, state, {...action.payload}):` you will not get that error.

Comment: You are all so right - I'm an idiot and needed fresh eyes on this. I was deconstructing an object in `Object.assign` when I needed to pass the object itself. @Eldar - if you post it as an answer, I'll accept and close with a big thank you.

Comment: No need for that, glad to help.

Comment: @Eldar Why do `{...action.payload}` it only does copy the object to deconstruct it once more in the `Object.assign` internals...

Comment: @Akxe it was just an example to show the correct syntax and you are right it is redundant.

Answer (score 1):

`Object.assign({}, state, ...action.payload)` is actually an invalid syntax. You have two options on how to fix it.

Either pass the object to the `Object.assign` as-is: `return Object.assign({}, state, action.payload)`

, or use the deconstruction, as it does the same thing but might offer better performance (for some engines) `return { ...state, ...action.payload }`.